# Python3 telnetlib write() issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, vxworks, telnetlib

I have issues sending byte strings via a VXWorks machine using telnet. I try to do the login example:

```
import telnetlib

tn = telnetlib.Telnet("192.168.45.61", port=23, timeout=5)
login = "administrator"
print(tn.read_until(b'login:').decode('ascii'))
tn.write(login.encode('ascii') + b'\r\n')
print(tn.read_until(b'Password:').decode('ascii'))
```

The output of the snippet is:

```
λ python tmp.py

VxWorks login:
 amnsrtr
Password:
```

Basically the string "administrator" is changed to " amnsrtr" by sending to the telnet server and reading it again. The login fails.
Could this be an encoding issue?
How to I find out which encoding the telnet-server is expecting?
I tried the login with the windosw telnet client and it worked. I checked the terminal-settings of the windows telnet client and found:
"current codepage: 850 (OEM - Multilingual Latin I)"
So I tried "cp850" and "latin-1" encoding, without success. I looped through all combinations of available text-encodings (encode -> decode) of the string "administrator" to see if anything yields " amnsrtr" with no result. The pattern I found is that basically every 2nd character is lost:

```
"administrator"
"a_m_n_s_r_t_r"
```

I don't know what to do with this though. Anyone any Idea what the issue could be?

I'm using Python 3.6.8 on Windows 10

Comment: A long shot, but perhaps something is expecting 'utf-16-le', but rather than decoding it properly, strips out every other byte?  So try encoding as 'utf-16-le' and see if that works.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunately that did not help. It only prints 'a' in the terminal: `VxWorks login: a`

Comment: Have you tried to connect with any other telnet clients?

Comment: @snakecharmerb Only the Windows telnet client as described in the question. As this worked without issues I assumed the issue is in the telnetlib/Python script.